# Reconfiguration of wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plesk

I recently mess up with my wordpress site. I try to redirect my site to another domain. I do the redirect via Plesk panel. It successfully redirect to another domain.

However, the problem is that when I try to reverse the action, the page cannot be browsed. I found out that the original wordpress files are disappeared (Which is previously located in the file manager). But the SQL database is still here.

So, I tried to reinstall wordpress and extract the files back into "httpdocs" and edit the "wp.config.example.php" to connect the corresponding database, user and password.

However, the page still cannot be browsed. Can anyone tell me what should I do to fix this?

P.S. I cannot login to the wordpress backstage (previous directory is my domain/wp-admin) as the page seems no longer exist.

Comment: You try to relocate a WordPress site from a host to another?
Can you explain what is the reversed action that couses your page can't be browsed?

Comment: Check the database (phpMyAdmin), in table wp_options, the both option names 'siteurl' and 'home', those should match your current domain.

Comment: delete wp-config.php. When you load the site it will create new one then you can change the settings.

Comment: Maybe I should explain clearly. I did redirect domainA via cPanel. I set the hosting to forward the domainA to domainB (located in another server). When I browsed domainA, it automatically browse domainB. This is good. 
However, when I cancel the forward action. DomainA cannot be browsed. I checked the file manager and the files are gone (all wordpress related files). Beside, I cannot load the wordpress login page too which the previous login URL is domainA/wp-admin. So, how can I call back the source files to get my site back?

Comment: The following video is exactly what I did. However, I change the setting in existing domain instead of adding new domain.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KtyN6bKwAis

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Make sure all files and directory are present in your httpdocs directory which are require for the wordpress also upload your theme if you are using any custom theme for your site.

And rename your **wp.config.example.php** TO **wp-config.php** and update your correct databases details in wp.config.php file then check your site again.